# Banco de Dados em CSV

Tags: java, python, web-service, r, csv

Se todo mundo ao criar aplicações na WEB ,Desktop ou Mobile precisa exportar ou importar dados tipo csv porque não criaram um SISTEMA GERENCIADOR DE BASE DE DADOS em csv ?

Resposta:Ja existe : http://adl-server.com.br/api/home.html

Comment: -1 Não é pergunta.

Comment: Nem sei o que dizer :|

Comment: Só depois de responder que eu percebi que era SPAM. Não estava entendendo os negativos. Sinalizem e votem para remover.

Answer (score 1):

Mas criaram: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/csv-storage-engine.html). E não serve como banco de dados de fato. O formato não permite a maioria das operações e garantias que se espera de um banco de dados.

De qualquer forma são coisas distintas. o formato CSV foi feito para transporte de dados. Foi feito para rodar em qualquer lugar sem a dependência de nenhum software específico.